# Calculate area with read and function

Tags: bash

I intend to calculate area of a circle.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a radius: " 
area () {
    a=$(( 3 * $REPLY * 2 ))
    return $a
}
echo $(area)
```

Run but return nothing

```
$ bash area.sh
Enter a radius: 9
```

Then to refactor it by quoting

```
#! /usr/local/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a radius: "  radius
area (radius) {
    a=$(( 3 * $radius * 2 ))
    return "$a"
}
echo "$(area)"
```

It still not work properly.

```
bash area.sh
Enter a radius: 9
area.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `radius'
area.sh: line 3: `area (radius) {'
```

How to do such a calculation?

Comment: The script you're running and the script you have shown as seem to be different. (There is no `area (radius) {` in your script.) Double check whatever it is you're running. Also, `return` sets the exit status of the function, whereas `$(area)` uses the output of the function. These are different.

Comment: ty. I modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in bash do not have named parameters. You cannot do:

```
area (foo) { ...
function area (foo) { ...
```

You can do:

```
area () {
    local radius a   # set a local variable that does not leak outside the function
    radius=$1   # Save the first parameter to local variable
    a=$(( 3 * radius * 2 ))
    echo "$a"
}
```

And then:

```
echo "$(area "$REPLY")"  # use $REPLY as the first argument
```

Since `return` sets the exit status of the function, whereas `$(area)` uses the output of the function. These are different.

Also, while bash does not support floating-point arithmetic, it does support exponentiation:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $((3 * 3 ** 2))'
27
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a quick script taking the input of the radius then feeding it to the function of `area()` then echoing out the return value.  This works with `bc` or binary calculator installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
function area(){
    circ=$(echo "3.14 * $1^2" | bc)
}

#Read in radius
read -p "Enter a radius: "

#Send REPLY to function
area $REPLY

#Print output
echo "Area of a circle is $circ"
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./circ.bsh 
Enter a radius: 6
Area of a circle is 113.04
```

Or I have expanded on the script a little to show more of reading in a variable either from the command line or from the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
function area(){
    areacirc=$(printf "3.14 * $1^2\n" | bc)
    diamcirc=$(printf "2 * $1\n" | bc)
    circcirc=$(printf "2 * 3.14 * $1\n" | bc)
}

#Read in radius from command line or from read
if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
    read -p "Enter a radius: "
else
    printf "Radius of a cirle is $1\n"
    REPLY=$1
fi

#Send REPLY to area function
area $REPLY

#Print output from variables set by area function
printf "Diameter of a circle is $diamcirc\n"
printf "Circumference of a circle is $circcirc\n"
printf "Area of a circle is $areacirc\n"
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./area.bsh 6
Radius of a cirle is 6
Diameter of a circle is 12
Circumference of a circle is 37.68
Area of a circle is 113.04
```

or

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./area.bsh
Enter a radius: 13
Diameter of a circle is 26
Circumference of a circle is 81.64
Area of a circle is 530.66
```

Comment: How to encapsulate the command into function area