# Is `return` within function a compulsory requirement?

Tags: bash

The the simpler form of a function is:

```
name () { commands return }
```

I find no difference in a function with and without return.
Suppose the minimal code:

```
step_forward (){
    echo "step one;"
    return
}
turn_around() {
    echo "turn around."
    return
}

step_forward
turn_around
```

Run and check the exit status:

```
$ bash testing.sh
step one;
turn around.
$ echo $?
0
```

Run it again after commenting out `return`

```
$ bash testing.sh
step one;
turn around.
$ echo $?
0
```

In what circumstances should a function end with a return?

Comment: `return` is not required.  Normally you would use it to return an exit value like 1 or 0 based on a test, but with your script you are not returning an exit value but only echoing out something, `return` is not needed at all.  A test is like `if [[ $value == "true" ]]; then return 0; else return 1; fi`

Comment: `name () { commands return }` ... why do you have `return` there? Who told you that's a simpler form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `return` value is not required in a function.  Normally a `return` would be used in a script for an exit value to be returned.  Exit values are normally like a `1` or a `0` where a lot of scripters might use it for a `0` as successful and a `1` as not successful.

```
#!/bin/bash
#The following function returns a value of 0 or 1
function if_running(){
    ps -ef | grep -w "$1" | grep -v grep > /dev/null
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

#Read in name of a running process
read -p "Enter a name of a process: "

#Send REPLY to function
if_running $REPLY

#Check return value and echo appropriately
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
   echo "Return value is $?"
   echo "$REPLY is running..."
else
   echo "Return value is $?"
   echo "$REPLY is not running..."
fi
```

Examples:

```
~$ ./ps_test.bsh 
Enter a name of a process: ls
Return value is 1
ls is not running...

~$ ./ps_test.bsh 
Enter a name of a process: bash
Return value is 0
bash is running...
```

And this answer I wrote a little bit ago does not have return values but still gives output  https://askubuntu.com/a/1023493/231142

```
#!/bin/bash
function area(){
    circ=$(echo "3.14 * $1^2" | bc)
}

#Read in radius
read -p "Enter a radius: "

#Send REPLY to function
area $REPLY

#Print output
echo "Area of a circle is $circ"
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./circ.bsh 
Enter a radius: 6
Area of a circle is 113.04
```

Hope this helps!